# python how download all file image,css, js from web url?

Tags: python, centos7

How can I list all file of a URL website in Python and download them in folder?

```
import uuid
rnd_str = uuid.uuid4().hex  
main_name="download_"+rnd_str
main_folder=main_name+"/"
dir = main_folder
if os.path.exists(dir):
    shutil.rmtree(dir)
os.mkdir(main_folder)

site = 'http://digipaz.com/'
response = requests.get(site)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
img_tags = soup.find_all('img')

urls = [img['src'] for img in img_tags]
for url in urls:
    filename = re.search(r'/([\w_-]+[.](jpg|gif|png|css))$', url)
    with open( '/home/danesh20016/public_html/ts/'+main_folder+filename.group(1), 'wb') as f:
        if 'http' not in url:
            # sometimes an image source can be relative 
            # if it is provide the base url which also happens 
            # to be the site variable atm. 
            url = '{}{}'.format(site, url)
        response = requests.get(url)
        f.write(response.content)
```

i can download image but not file  js,css

Comment: You are only searching for 'img'. Check this [link](https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/extract-web-page-script-and-css-files-in-python) for css and js.

Comment: yes but need to find all css and js in loop

Comment: You can just code another loop for css/js files, dont you?

Comment: how get js and css ?

Comment: `soup.find.all("script")` for js and `soup.find.all("link")` for css, just read the link that I gave you in my first comment.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: i want find  all link file and image,css,js for download and save it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pip._vendor import requests
import os
import shutil
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import uuid

rnd_str = uuid.uuid4().hex
main_name="download_"+rnd_str
main_folder= main_name+"/"
dir = main_folder

if os.path.exists(dir):
    shutil.rmtree(dir)
os.mkdir(main_folder)


site = 'http://digipaz.com/'
response = requests.get(site)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
#find all jpg,png,gif
img_tags = soup.find_all('img')
urls = [img['src'] for img in img_tags]
#print (urls)
for url in urls:
    filename = re.search(r'/([\w_-]+[.](jpg|gif|png))$', url)
   #with open( '/home/danesh20016/public_html/ts/'+main_folder+filename.group(1), 'wb') as f:
    print (url)
    with open( '/home/danesh20016/public_html/ts/'+main_folder+filename.group(1), 'wb') as f:
    #with open(main_folder+filename.group(1), 'wb') as f:
        if 'http' not in url:
            # sometimes an image source can be relative
            # if it is provide the base url which also happens
            # to be the site variable atm.
            url = '{}{}'.format(site, url)
        response = requests.get(url)
        f.write(response.content)

 #find all css  
 for link in soup.findAll('link', href=True):
    #print ("Found the URL:", link['href'])
    if re.search(".css", link['href']):
       print (link['href'])
       with open('/home/danesh20016/public_html/ts/'+main_folder+ filename.group(1), 'wb') as f:
           # with open(main_folder+filename.group(1), 'wb') as f:
           if 'http' not in url:
               # sometimes an image source can be relative
               # if it is provide the base url which also happens
               # to be the site variable atm.
               url = '{}{}'.format(site, link['href'])
           response = requests.get(url)
           f.write(response.content)
#find all js
link_js = [sc["src"] for sc in soup.find_all("script",src=True)]
for link in link_js:
    print ("Found the URL:", link)
    with open('/home/danesh20016/public_html/ts/'+main_folder+ filename.group(1), 'wb') as f:
        # with open(main_folder+filename.group(1), 'wb') as f:
        if 'http' not in url:
            # sometimes an image source can be relative
            # if it is provide the base url which also happens
            # to be the site variable atm.
            url = '{}{}'.format(site, link)
        response = requests.get(url)
        f.write(response.content)
```

Comment: When handling links I think you want to exclude those with `rel='preconnect'`, `rel=dns-prefetch`, `rel='pingback'`, etc.